# Best method for troubleshooting "hiccups" in xCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, sprite-kit

I've been working on a small iPhone game using SpriteKit.  Periodically the game will "hiccup" and freeze for a half a second before resuming (Activity monitor shows CPU usage drop to 0%).  I don't really have a lead as to where things might be freezing up, and I'm unfamiliar with the tools xCode provides to solve these issues.  I've experimented with setting up breakpoints and looking for where things freeze up, but I don't think it's the right way to solve the problem. What is the methodology for solving brief and seemingly random runtime issues that aren't easily reproduced?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might want to look into Instruments, a performance measurement tool bundled with Xcode.

Comment: Most likely candidate is resource loading, ie creating a sprite that uses a huge texture for the first time. Or creating a lot of nodes at once. You can also hit the pause button at the freeze time and check the callstack to see where the app is currently at.

Comment: You can also look at the debugging properties on your `SKView`: `showsFPS`, `showsDrawCount`, `showsNodeCount` and `showsPhysics`